# it is necesarry androidtestcompile? what is it for?

Tags: android, gradle, build

I'am a beginner in AndroidStudio. My first hello world app is stucked in gradle resolving dependencies (app:_debugAndroidTestApk)... it tooks a lot of time doing that so I want to know what is doing.

Also I found in build.gradle that there are two lines I do not know what they are for:

```
androidTestCompile ...
testCompile ...
```

Can someone explain in a very basic way what this is all about?

Answer (score 1):

- testCompile is the configuration for unit tests, which test data and behavior (located in src/test)
- androidTestCompile is used to run tests on your API and any instrumentation tests (located in src/androidTest). These tests run on a physical device or emulator.